# Does "Destroy all creatures with power 4 or greater" also affect *my* creatures?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Does "Destroy all creatures with power 4 or greater" also affect *my* creatures? I have a planeswalker card that has this ability; will it also kill my creatures? Also, this only affects creatures on the battlefield, not in players' hands, right?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It will destroy your creatures as well. Just read the card literally. There's nothing there to imply that your creatures would be excluded. As for players' hands, the word "creature" by default means "a creature card or token on the battlefield." You cannot have a "creature" in your hand, you can only have a "creature card" in your hand. Finally, note that "destroy" would have no meaning when used on a card in your hand, it would have to say "discard" to remove a card from your hand.

Comment: It's useful to note that Elspeth, Sun's Champion makes 1/1 tokens that go up to 3 power if you manage to make an emblem. Thus there isn't much drawback to the second ability being able to hit your own creatures.

Comment: @HaoYe: Yes, I see. But I guess I need to be careful to make the emblem AFTER the destroy if I don't want to kill a precious creature in the process. Thanks for pointing all this out!